# Python builder script with Windows-specific subprocess.py error - Cannot find file

Tags: python, subprocess, trigger.io

I'm following the build tutorial / set-up instructions for Trigger.io's extension framework [here](https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions/blob/master/README.md). Once it gets to `proc = Popen(minify_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)` in the last file, something in `subprocess` bugs out.

It appears to be a Windows-only issue. Here's the trace:

```
(python-env) C:\Users\name\Desktop\browser-extensions.git\_something>forge-ext
ension build chrome
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.62

...

[   INFO] appended common-v2/api-suffix.js to chrome/forge/all.js
[   INFO] appended common-v2/api-suffix.js to chrome/forge/all-priv.js
[   INFO] deleting 1 files
[   INFO] applying templates to 2 files
[   INFO] minifying 2 files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\browser-extensions.git\python-env\Scripts\forge-
extension-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    load_entry_point('generate==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'forge-extension')()
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\build_tools\main
.py", line 227, in main
    COMMANDS[command](*other_args)
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\build_tools\main
.py", line 94, in command_build
    forge_generate.main()
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\generate\main.py
", line 237, in main
    return generator.run()
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\generate\main.py
", line 107, in run
    self.build.run()
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\generate\build.p
y", line 308, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\generate\build.p
y", line 267, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\generate\server_
tasks.py", line 115, in minify_in_place
    minify.minify_in_place(build.source_dir, *real_files)
  File "c:\users\name\desktop\browser-extensions.git\generate\generate\minify.
py", line 32, in minify_in_place
    proc = Popen(minify_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

(python-env) C:\Users\name\Desktop\browser-extensions.git\_something>
```

Comment: Can you print out what those `minify_args` are? Is it referring to a program you don't have on your `PATH`? Because that's exactly the error you get in that case… Did you install all of the dependencies listed on the install page, update your `PATH` in the Control Panel, and start a new shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, it's trying to run `java`: https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions/blob/master/generate/generate/minify.py#L30

You need Java installed and the `java` program in your PATH. Fairly sure installing the JRE should solve your problem: http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Comment: That was it - for some reason it didn't update PATH on install.